# I have a problem with adding particles on a surface

Tags: particles

so, I started a Blender Guru donut tutorial, I'm on part 1, level 2: particles. I am not able to make my particles (sprinkles on the donut) go on the upper part of the donut (icing). The tutorial tells you to switch to "hair" in the particles panel and then render to object, after that select the object (in my case a cylinder) to become particles on the icing of the donut. In my case: the particles take the form of the icing, but float on top of it, the particles are like stuck to the icing so I can't put them on the icing manually. I tried to modify the "object" settings, but the particles just disappear.
Edit: I managed to fix the problem.

the link to the tutorial: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&index=9)

here's what it looks like:
[image].
[image: the donut]
[image: my settings]
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: You say "in my case a cylinder", yet in the Render Object I see "Sphere".  1) are you selecting the correct particle object?  2) for you cylinder particle object, set its location to 0,0,0, or else each instance may be offset.   Also try varying the Scale, or deselecting Object Scale which will help you play around with object particles that became too small to see.